# Can't convert unix epoch / timestamp to proper time

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, unix-timestamp

I am getting timestamps for estimated bus arrival times from an API as a timestamp / epoch: `1536589019000`. If I go to a website like [this](https://www.epochconverter.com/) I get the appropriate format:

Monday, September 10, 2018 7:16:59 AM

But if I attempt to convert the date in javascript, for example, with momentjs, I get some date far into the future: `50662-08-08 08:03`

```
moment.unix(estimatedArrivalTime).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")
```

How do I convert a unix timestamp properly?

Comment: You're getting a timestamp in millesconds instead of seconds. Just passing it like so should work: `moment(1536589019000).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")`

Comment: Yep - I'll accept this if you post it (Had to also run parseInt, as for some reason the timestamp was coming back in generic format)

Comment: The Unix timestamp counts the seconds since 1970-01-01, it's format is in seconds and not in milliseconds

Comment: This is why people need to read docs. :) The millisecond and second with unix() is right beside each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a timestamp in millesconds instead of seconds. Just passing it like so should work: `moment(1536589019000).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")`

Answer (score 2):

divide the time by thousand , moment.unix() expects time to be in **seconds**

```
moment.unix(1536589019).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")
```

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/ or use https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/